# Optmizing a function scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am new to python and statistical programming. For a class assignment we've been asked to implement python lasso L1 regression. 
This involves using a QP solver to solve .

```
0.5 *(x^t * H * x) + f^t * H
st x > 0 (every element of x is greater than zero)
```

These are block vectors and matrices. I am using 2 dimensional arrays for vectors and  four dimensional array for the matrix H

```
def function(x):
    x = x.reshape(2, -1)
    return 0.5*np.tensordot(x,(np.tensordot(H,x,([1,3],[0,1]))),([0,1],[0,1])) + np.tensordot(f,x,([0,1],[0,1]))

initial_val = np.random.randn(2 * (k+1)).reshape((2,k+1))

bnds = (0,None)
theta = scipy.optimize.minimize(function, initial_val, method="SLSQP", bounds=bnds)
```

But still I am getting negative values in `theta.x` vector. Could anyone tell me Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You'll need to provide some more information, namely what you called `function` and `initial_val`, the error might lie with those.

Comment: I think x0 (initial_val) needs to be a vector, not a matrix.

bnds needs to be of the same length as initial_val.

It's difficult to reproduce your error without examples of H, f, and k.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide constraints for the optimization, like this if you optimize a scalar function:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(
    function,
    initial_val,
    method="SLSQP",
    bounds=bnds,
    constraints = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda x: x}])
```

or for vector functions:

```
constraints = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda x: x[i]} \
                   for i in range(len(initial_val))]
```

Note that if it's a vector, then you also need to provide bounds for each element:

```
 bnds = [(0, None) for _ in range(len(initial_val))]
```

You might also want to look at the [reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize).

Comment: Although I got the result I was looking for I am still getting negative values in x vector after optimization. I used 
constraints = [{'type' : 'ineq', 'fun' : lambda x: x[i]} for i in range(len(initial))] . I can't understand why

Comment: @AdaXu Have you verified that the optimization was successful (`result.success` and `result.message` attributes)? If yes, what do you mean that you got the result you were looking for and `x` had negative elements? I thought negative elements were not the result you were looking for.

Comment: result.message - Optimization terminated successfully
and the regression curve fits well. 
But there are negative values in result.x I don't know what to make of this

Comment: @AdaXu Could you paste here the line with the `minimize` function call, and the actual values of `result.x`? Or maybe into pastebin? If I won't be able to help right away I'd suggest another question, but maybe it's a quick thing.

Comment: I figured it out. The vector argument initial_val is actually a 2  dimension numpy array since my objective function involves block matrix H with 4 dimensions and block vectors with two dimensions. I changed them to ordinary 2 dimensional matrix and one dim vector and I get the right answer. If you can modify your answer for 2 dim constraint I will mark it as correct. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @AdaXu The second option in my answer already covers any dimensional constraint. Note that it generates as many constraints as needed for the length of vector `initial_val`, so it will also work for 2 dimensions.